# GridView, ItemTemplate, DataTemplate binding in C# code behind

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have following working XAML and C# code behind:

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100" Width="150">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </StackPanel.Background>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

**CODE behind:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var _Colors = typeof(Colors)
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Color = (Color)x.GetValue(null),
            Name = x.Name
        });
    this.DataContext = _Colors;
}
```

This works fine.

But I want to do all the XAML part in C# code behind. In XAML, only `MainGrid` will be there, all its child elements and bindings needs to be done in code behind.

I have tried something like this in `MainPage_Loaded` event:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView gridView = new GridView()
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate
            {
                //Don't know what to add here
            }
        };

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Binding bindingObject = new Binding();
        bindingObject.Source = this;
        grid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundProperty, bindingObject);

        //...
        // Don't know how to add grid inside gridView in Code.
        //...

        MainGrid.Children.Add(gridView);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to advise you not to create elements in code unless you have a real good reason to do so.

Regardless, considering that item templates are factory-like objects for controls (you 'spawn' a new set of controls for each item). You use the [FrameworkElementFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) to model the subtree and then assign that the item template's [VisualTree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.visualtree(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Sorry But FrameworkElementFactory, VisualTree seems confusing to me.